# VirtualBox (Lubuntu) guests randomly dying when I sleep the (Windows 10) host

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, sleep

Half or maybe even most/all of the time when I close my laptop (which, I believe, sends Windows (which I believe is called the "host"(?)) to sleep), when I open it again, my VirtualBox Lubuntu VM (the "guest"(?)) is at the login screen, and when I log in, it is like a brand new VM / session: no programs are open anymore.  So it seems like the VM is restarting for some reason and I'm losing all of my work as a result.

What could be causing this, and how can I debug it?

EDIT: update: After I manually suspend the guest, and then resume, my session flashes on the screen for <1 second, and then I am back at the login screen; and as before, after I log in, my session is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to suspend the guest machine first before you suspend Windows 10. Then your guest machine will restart properly. I do that with my guest machines.

You can even suspend the machine, and shut the host down.

Comment: Do you know why that's the case?
And do you know if there's a way to automate that process?

Comment: I do this to prevent the guest from crashing which can happen. Depends on apps and versions. Just safer to suspend first

Comment: I did some looking and I do not think there is any way to automate suspending. Suspend when you are done with the machine. Suspending may for you and does for me allow me to shut the host machine down if the guest has been suspended

Comment: I think it's actually the resuming from suspension that is failing; see my EDIT to the OP.

Comment: You can easily verify this by suspending the guest machine first, then suspend or shut down the host machine, then start up (wake up) the host machine and see if the guest wakes up properly. I do this and my guests are fine when they wake up.

Comment: I have verified it as following, as noted in my EDIT to the OP:

"EDIT: update: After I manually suspend the guest, and then resume, my session flashes on the screen for <1 second, and then I am back at the login screen; and as before, after I log in, my session is gone."

Comment: @DavidScottKrueger did you manage to root cause the issue? I've recently moved my VM to a new laptop and noticed that same thing happens there as well - when I wake it from the sleep, the VM may momentarily flash the old state and then it's back to the login screen with all of the apps closed.

Answer (score 0):

In general I think John is incorrect; you shouldn't need to do anything special in the VM because the host should treat it just as another program, and handle power management for it. Typically guest power management is disabled (greyed out) because the host handles all of it.

What is your window's host set to do when you close the lid? (Check power management settings in windows). This matters a lot - it sounds like it's set to sleep after a certain period of time, and you don't have any issues as long as the lid is just closed (but not sleeping), but you have problems if windows goes to sleep, or maybe hibernates (this is why you should check what your windows is set to do, so you know what is causing the issue).

This might be helpful, especially if you've recently updated windows, changed hyperV settings, or changed shared folder settings. E.g. if the VM expects the shared folders to be in a certain state, and the host changes that state (by sleeping or hibernating), that could cause a crash. So you could try disabling your shared folders and see if it still happens.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dc043b1d-9a8e-4825-bc7e-55d3eb035f66/win81-sleep-what-happens-to-vms-?forum=w8itprovirt

Did this always happen, or start all of a sudden? If it just started, do you remember any changes you made recently? What version of vitrualbox are you using? Have you tried updating it / rolling back the most recent update and reinstalling it?

The best troubleshooting thing you could do is to reliably recreate the issue: e.g. run something in the VM, choose sleep from the windows menu, resume, and see what happens in the VM. Try the same thing for hibernate.

Comment: please see EDIT to OP